# A boss or the boss /the misunderstandings or misunderstandings

Tags: articles

Which article should be use in this sentence:

- When a person has ***the/no article*** misunderstandings with ***a/the*** boss, he or she should act in a proper way.

It is a general sentence

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to tell a little more about what you already know or think about these choices.

Comment: It is a general sentence, and I am a little bit confused about the use of articles there

Comment: These misunderstandings are a general thing, but you only have one boss, usually.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer should be in this way:
When a person has misunderstandings with the boss, he or she should act in a proper way.
And I think one can use some before misunderstandings word rather than an article.

Comment: Or "with _their_ boss".

Comment: I think with the boss has to be used as they have the option to use articles only.

Comment: Using *some* like "When a person has some misunderstandings" does not sound idiomatic in US English (it sounds very "Indian English" to Americans).   We would be more likely to say "a misunderstanding" or "misunderstandings" (no determiner).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There's some hint with "misunderstandings": it's plural, so "the" won't work. I think the question wants you to choose "no article," though in my opinion "I *have misunderstandings with* her" is not as idiomatic as "I have *a misunderstanding* with her." (This is like the similar phrase "have **an** argument with," where the article is absolutely required.)

For "**a/the boss**, "**a**" is most likely. The sentence has created a broad, generic sentence that can be true of any "person," so the indefinite article makes sense. "The boss" could perhaps be used, but this is a casual usage that uses the definite article to mean "the boss [in their particular situation]," and I doubt the question means to ask about this usage.